# Magento AdvancedSmtp sender email

Tags: email, magento, smtp

I have a stie develop in Magento.
To send email I need an smtp extension, I have installed AdvancedSmtp.
I have configure my smtp with my server and now when I send email from contact or other form my sender email is noreply@mydomain.com
But if I want to change the Sender email how can I do that?
I have tried to change it into:
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php the function sendTransactional (because I have seen that into the controller of contact it call this function) I have chagen this for example

```
$this->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_' . $sender . '/name', $storeId));
$this->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_' . $sender . '/email', $storeId));
```

to

```
$this->setSenderEmail('info@otherdomain.com');
$this->setSenderName('info@otherdomain.com');
```

but it always send with noreply@mydomain.com

I have change its controller in:
app/code/community/Mage/Advancedsmtp/Model/Email/Template.php

```
$mail->setFrom($this->getSenderEmail(), $this->getSenderName());
```

to

```
$mail->setFrom('info@otherdomain.com', 'test');
```

it change the name of the mail but not the sender. How can I solve this?

Comment: have you searched for the string 'noreply@mydomain.com' in the module's code?

Comment: no there isn't @OSdave

Comment: Does it work with bare PHP code, e.g. with code posed here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php ? I have a vague memory of some settings in php.ini of apache or so that conflicted with setting your own `from` in the header of the email...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know 
SMTP ( postfix ) you need to confirm/configure the sender email

So you need to check the server mail.log

for instance you might see something like this error

> Could not resolve sender domain. (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

This means the sender email is not verified and you need to create real email address on the server.

So i think in your case postfix configured to send all out emails with noreply@mydomain.com

its not related to the code and magento.

Comment: The server resolve the sender domain this error isn't in the log file

Comment: Can you show the result from the mail log file for the emails you try to send ?

Comment: There isn't error in the log I have search and is very long.. it send normally with the email that authenticate the smtp

Comment: it should report success sent or no and all information like sender and the domain resolve etc.. ! 
Example 
Mar 13 10:35:47 desado postfix/qmgr[10982]: C790811408F5: from=<fromemail@domain.com>, size=1211, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 13 10:35:47 postfix/smtpd[2454]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 13 10:35:55 postfix/smtp[2458]: C790811408F5: to=<toemail@domain.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.79.26]:25, delay=7.9, delays=0.09/0/3.5/4.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1363156534 pu7si33993046pbc.172 - gs

Comment: you have to have logs which will explain the configuration etc.. also paste postfix configuration here.

Log file : /var/log/mail.log

Comment: is the problem fixed ? share the answer so it helps everyone :) Cheers !